# Maven password encryption BadPaddingException

Tags: maven, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt a server password in my settings.xml and I'm getting this exception when trying to deploy an artifact.

```
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:811)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:676)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:313)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2087)
    at org.sonatype.plexus.components.cipher.PBECipher.decrypt64(PBECipher.java:185)
    ... 18 more
```

here's the excerpt from the xml

```
<server>
            <id>server</id>
            <username>username</username>
            <password>{N8AF8BmQ5x8HZX/yrlrP1QiKNMEdoXWyBFZd/*zIabY=}</password> 
        </server>
```

the same exception is also happening for my master password, I just followed the instructions here
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html
created a security-settings.xml like in the guide, executed these two commands and copied the encrypted passwords into the appropriate xml files.

```
mvn --encrypt-master-password <password>
mvn --encrypt-password <password>
```

Comment: In rare cases there's an escaping issue, not sure if that's happening here. Consider regenerating both emp and ep (their values will be different every time)

Comment: I'm assuming emp and ep mean the master and server password?

Comment: -emp = --encrypt-master-password, -ep = --encrypt-password (see mvn -h or mvn --help :) )

Comment: @RobertScholte Could you please insert your comment as an answer so it can be marked as accepted? Your solution is useful but could not be noticed as a comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In rare cases there's an escaping issue, that's probably happening here. Consider regenerating the masterpassword (with -emp or --encrypt-master-password) and/or password ( with -ep or --encrypt-password) . Their values will be different every time.

Comment: Initially, the encrypted master password Maven generated for me contained a '+'. I suspect that could trigger this error, because on second try it generated one without a '+' and everything was fine.

Comment: strangely, I had the same issue out of no where, I've used the same master password for over a year, after regenerating the master-password it worked again - odd

Answer (score 7):

Or maybe by accident you copy-pasted the wrong parameter:

```
--encrypt-master-password
```

and put the output in settings.xml instead of:

```
--encrypt-password
```

which got me into trouble. (Darn password expiration policies)

Answer (score 3):

Let's understand the problem here.

mvn encryption password is used to ensure secured access to the protected repository servers (possible Nexus or JFrog).

This access is based on 2 settings.

1. Common settings available in <MAVEN_HOME>/conf/settings.xml which will define the list of repositories and required username password for them. A typical entry would look like below

```html
<server>
      <id>my.server</id>
      <username>foo</username>
      <password>{COQLCE6DU6GtcS5P=}</password>
 </server>
```

To have a password for this file, the command is

```
mvn --encrypt-password <password>
```

2. User specific settings available in local repo path (can be found in the <MAVEN_HOME>/conf/settings.xml) something like C:/Users/user/.m2/settings-security.xml which looks like below

```html
<settingsSecurity>
  <master>{jSMOWnoPFgsHVpMvz5VrIt5kRbzGpI8u+9EF1iFQyJQ=}</master>
</settingsSecurity>
```

To have a password for this file the mvn command is

```
mvn --encrypt-master-password <password>
```

Now the exception mentioned in the question is mostly the potential side effect of accidentally copying the password generated by  `mvn --encrypt-password <password>` in the settings-security.file instead of using password generated by `mvn --encrypt-master-password <password>`

So double check your steps and it should solve the issue.

For detailed reference visit [Maven - Password Encryption](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html)

Answer (score 0):

Came across the same issue. Solved it by:

1) generating encrypted password using quotes around my password as opposed to no quotes (this seemed to remove the +)

e.g.
`mvn -emp "myPassword123"` and `mvn -ep "myPassword123"`

instead of `mvn -emp myPassword123` and `mvn -ep myPassword123`

2) making sure my settings.xml and settings-security.xml were in the correct directories. (i have my settings.xml in the maven install directory and the settings-security.xml in the .m2 directory)

This worked for me anyway

ps. i had to close terminal after editing settings file as i think it was doing some sort of caching

Comment: Instead of supplying the password in the command line, which has security issues (shoulder surfers, stored command history, etc.), just run `mvn -ep` (or `-emp`) and let it prompt for invisible password entry. Note if you're on Git Bash you'll want to use `winpty mvn.cmd` instead as mintty will otherwise display the password you type.

Answer (score 0):

I copied a wrong password into masterpassword field. After all I removed it so security xml contains no password, and regeneration starts to work.